# How to smooth the joint of lines in bezier path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a cuboid shape using `UIBezierPath`. My drawing code is below:

( (x, y) is origin of my `UIView` and (h, w) is its size)

```
UIBezierPath *bpath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bpath1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h * 0.4)];
[bpath1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h)];
[bpath1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w - (w * 0.4), y + h)];
[bpath1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w - (w * 0.4), y + h * 0.4)];
[bpath1 closePath];


UIBezierPath *bpath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bpath2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.4, y)];
[bpath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y)];
[bpath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w - (w * 0.4), y + h * 0.4];
[bpath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h * 0.4];
[bpath2 closePath];

UIBezierPath *bpath3 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bpath3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y)];
[bpath3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y + h - (h * 0.4))];
[bpath3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w - (w * 0.4), y + h)];
[bpath3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w - (w * 0.4), y + h * 0.4];
[bpath3 closePath];
```

I created 3 paths because I wanted different alpha values for every path. I got the desired output which is below:

[image: General output]

But to my surprise for very few values of `h`(height), I got the shape as below:

[image: Strange shape for some <code>h</code> values]

Now, number of values for which this shape comes up is very few. Since rendering code is same every time, I don't understand this strange behaviour of bezier paths. Why bezier path is showing this behaviour and is there any way to smooth these joints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are drawing on the UIView then the solution of adam works. But if you are drawing on `CaShapeLayer` (as in my case), then you have to set the `lineJoin` property of your `shapeLayer`, not the path. 
This solution is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164748/unable-to-get-rid-of-spike-on-bezier-path).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `lineCapStyle` and `lineJoinStyle`. Specifically, I think it's because the `lineJoinStyle` is defaulting to Miter, and either changing it to Round or changing the `miterLimit`.

I believe this has the same solution as [UIBezierPath not drawing a smooth curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896557/uibezierpath-not-drawing-a-smooth-curve)

Comment: So how to calculate miterLimit value? The link you provided says to set the value to -10, which doesn't solve the problem.